# Can I manipulate a Textbox in an html based Google Apps Script Sidebar through a function associated to a button in that Sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Question coming from someone who started coding GAS 3 days ago. I'm trying to transfer a tool I developed as an Excel VBA Add-In with Windows Forms into Google Workspace. I apologize in advance if this is potentially something that simply isn't possible in GAS/HTML.

I'll try to describe the use case as simply as possible:

I have implemented a sidebar in Google Sheets with multiple text boxes for user input. I have successfully transferred inputs from the HTML textboxes into the GAS part of things.
Now, I have a field that is pre-filled in with a date. Below are two buttons. These should be used for the convenience of increasing the date in said textbox by a number of days (+1 day; +3 days; etc.).

So clicking on +1 should automatically increase the displayed value in the textbox by 1 day.

I'm trying to implement exactly that functionality. As of now I have successfully handed over the value in the textbox to a GAS function that increases the date by 1 (even that almost made me lose my mind compared to how this is done in VBA :( ). Now I want to transfer that new date back into the text box.

After trying to search for any similar use case almost the entire day, I gave up and registered here for help. The only comparable things I could find with regards to transferring values from GAS to HTML used these values in the createHtmlOutputFromFile function to hand them over when creating and launching the sidebar. In my case I want the value in the textbox to change while the sidebar is open.

I rely on this not only for something as trivial as increasing a date, but for the sake of clarity this was one of the easiest examples to explain.

Thanks for any help in advance!!

**UPDATE WITH CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<base target="_top">
<!-- Google Style Sheet to make it look"google" :) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<style>
  .block {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 10px;

  }
  label {
    font-size: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
  }
  input {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  button {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  select {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body>
 <form id="dashboardForm">
  <!-- HTML code that defines the sidebar structure -->
  <p>Please provide your inputs for the RfX event creation</p>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Project Name:</label>
    <input name="projectName" value="TestProject">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Type:</label>
    <select name="RfXtype">
      <option value="RfP">RfP</option>
      <option value="RfI">RfI</option>
      <option value="ePROC">ePROC</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Commodity Code:</label>
    <input name="comCode" value="CAPC">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Due Date:</label>
    <input name="dueDate" value="01/01/2021">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <input type="button" value="+1" onclick="google.script.run.add1Day(dashboardForm)">
    <input type="button" value="+3" onclick="google.script.run.add3Day(dashboardForm)">
    <input type="button" value="+7" onclick="google.script.run.add7Day(dashboardForm)">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Technical Contact:</label>
    <input name="techContact" value="Test">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact E-Mail:</label>
    <input name="contactMail" value="Test" disabled>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Phone:</label>
    <input name="contactPhone" value="Test123" disabled>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Name:</label>
    <input name="contactName" value="Thorsten Platz" disabled>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>E-Mail Language:</label>
    <select name="mailLanguage">
      <option value="English">English</option>
      <option value="German">German</option>
      <option value="French">French</option>
      <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Incoterms:</label>
    <select name="Incoterms">
      <option value="DDP">DDP</option>
      <option value="DAP">DAP</option>
      <option value="FCA">FCA</option>
      <option value="ExWorks">ExWorks</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Delivery Adress:</label>
    <input name="dAdress" value="Immenstaad">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Offer Validity:</label>
    <input name="oValidity" value="31/12/2021">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Payment Terms:</label>
    <select name="Incoterms">
      <option value="60EOM10">60EOM10</option>
      <option value="30EOM10">30EOM10</option>
      <option value="15EOM10">15EOM10</option>
      <option value="00EOM10">00EOM10</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Delivery Date:</label>
    <input name="delDate" value="31/12/2021">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Purchasing Entity</label>
    <select name="pEntity">
      <option value="TestGmbH">TEST GmbH</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>End Customer</label>
    <input name="endCus" value="BAAINBw">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <label>Currency</label>
    <select name="Curr">
      <option value="EUR">EUR (€)</option>
      <option value="GBP">GBP (£)</option>
      <option value="USD">USD ($)</option>
      <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label>BoM</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="BoM">
  <label>SOW</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="SOW">
  <label>ECCD (Word)</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ECCDW">
  <label>ECCD (Excel)</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ECCDE"> 

  <input type="button" value="Create Project" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
  <input type="button" value="Create Email only" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
  <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the .gs part:

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc       //Limits the script to only accessing the current spreadsheet

var SIDEBAR_TITLE = "Dashboard";

function onOpen(e) {
  //Custom Menu with functions
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("CM-Tracker")
    .addItem("Open Dashboard", "dashOpen")
    .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}

function dashOpen() {
  //Open the Dashboard as a Sidebar from an HTML File
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Dashboard.html");
  widget.setTitle(SIDEBAR_TITLE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);
}
```

Comment: What's the reason behind using an editor add-on instead of a workspace one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeking can be accomplished all within the sidebar html like so...

**UPDATED HTML**
So, I've added my code with these changes...

1. Appended `<br>` to `<label>Due Date:</label>`
2. To `<input name="dueDate" value="01/01/2021">` added `type="date" id="dueDate"` resulting in `<input type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="01/01/2021">`
3. Added `value="<?!=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Los_Angeles','yyyy-MM-dd');?>"` to auto populate the date field with today's date - refer to:[Class HTML Template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template)
4. To the `value="+1 ,+3, +7" onclick` I added `update(1)`, `update(3)`, `update(7)` respectively and commented your function calls to `google.script.run.yourFunction()`.
5. You can click on the "date" field and it will bring up a calendar to choose a date, or add days via the buttons.
6. Inserted `<script></script>` below the `</form>` tag.
7. Modified the `dashOpen()` gs function  (see below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- Google Style Sheet to make it look"google" :) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
    <style>
        .block {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 10px;

        }

        label {
            font-size: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 90px;
        }

        input {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        button {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        select {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="dashboardForm">
        <!-- HTML code that defines the sidebar structure -->
        <p>Please provide your inputs for the RfX event creation</p>

        <div class="block">
            <label>Project Name:</label>
            <input name="projectName" value="TestProject">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Type:</label>
      <select name="RfXtype">
        <option value="RfP">RfP</option>
        <option value="RfI">RfI</option>
        <option value="ePROC">ePROC</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Commodity Code:</label>
      <input name="comCode" value="CAPC">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Due Date:</label><br>
      <input type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="01/01/2021">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <input type="button" value="+1" onclick="update(1)//google.script.run.add1Day(dashboardForm)">
      <input type="button" value="+3" onclick="update(3)//google.script.run.add3Day(dashboardForm)">
      <input type="button" value="+7" onclick="update(7)//google.script.run.add7Day(dashboardForm)">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Technical Contact:</label>
      <input name="techContact" value="Test">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact E-Mail:</label>
      <input name="contactMail" value="Test" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Phone:</label>
      <input name="contactPhone" value="Test123" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Name:</label>
      <input name="contactName" value="Thorsten Platz" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>E-Mail Language:</label>
      <select name="mailLanguage">
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="German">German</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>
        <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Incoterms:</label>
      <select name="Incoterms">
        <option value="DDP">DDP</option>
        <option value="DAP">DAP</option>
        <option value="FCA">FCA</option>
        <option value="ExWorks">ExWorks</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Delivery Adress:</label>
      <input name="dAdress" value="Immenstaad">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Offer Validity:</label>
      <input name="oValidity" value="31/12/2021">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Payment Terms:</label>
      <select name="Incoterms">
        <option value="60EOM10">60EOM10</option>
        <option value="30EOM10">30EOM10</option>
        <option value="15EOM10">15EOM10</option>
        <option value="00EOM10">00EOM10</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Delivery Date:</label>
      <input name="delDate" value="31/12/2021">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Purchasing Entity</label>
      <select name="pEntity">
        <option value="TestGmbH">TEST GmbH</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>End Customer</label>
      <input name="endCus" value="BAAINBw">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <label>Currency</label>
      <select name="Curr">
        <option value="EUR">EUR (€)</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP (£)</option>
        <option value="USD">USD ($)</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <label>BoM</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="BoM">
    <label>SOW</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SOW">
    <label>ECCD (Word)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ECCDW">
    <label>ECCD (Excel)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ECCDE">

    <input type="button" value="Create Project" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
    <input type="button" value="Create Email only" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="google.script.run.createProject()">
  </form>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function update(increment){
    let element = document.getElementById("dueDate");    
      element.defaultValue = element.stepUp(increment);
    };
  </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

**Modified dashOpen function**

```
function dashOpen() {
  //Open the Dashboard as a Sidebar from an HTML File
  var widget = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile("Dashboard")
  .evaluate()
  .setTitle(SIDEBAR_TITLE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);

}
```

**SOME THEORY**

1. Use google script (gs) codes to serve an HTML file (`HtmlService`) to your sidebar.
2. If you want to have gs serve dynamic data with `<?= ?>` tags, you will need to use `HtmlService.getTemplateFromFile('filename').evaluate()`
   **NOTE** *you can place any gs code between `<?= ?>` or `<?!= ?>` to be `evaluated` when `HtmlService` is called.*
3. From the sidebar (webpage), the user changes `<input>` fields on the form and presses `<button>` fields from web page to execute a `<script>` function from within the `<body>` tag of the web page.
4. The sidebar `<script>` functions can retrieve the data from the sidebar fields, validate the data, and scrub any malicious code (preprocess) then send the data to a google script with `google.script.run.yourGoogleScriptFuntion()`
5. if you use `.withSuccessHandler(successFunction)` & `.withFailureHandler(failedFunction)`, you can update the sidebar with data returned from the gs and processed with the `successFunction` or, upon failure to process, execute the `failedFunction`, which can be used to notify the user of and error or failure.
6. Example html ...

```
<html>
<body>
.
.
.
<input type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="01/01/2021">
<div id=“someId”></div>
.
.
.
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="myWebPageFunction()">
.
.
.
<!-- CLIENT SIDE SCRIPTS IN THE SIDEBAR HTML -->
<script> 
function myWebPageFunction() { 
  // get data from <input> with 
  var dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate').getValue();
  // pass variable 'dueDate' to gs to process with
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onReturn).withFailureHandler(onFailure).someGsScript(dueDate);
}

function onReturn(newVariablePassedFromGoogleScript){
  // EXAMPLE 1 - upon successful execution of the google script you can update an html elements value with...
  document.getElementById('dueDate').value = newVariablePassedFromGoogleScript;

  // OR EXAMPLE 2 you can change the html display content with...
  document.getElementById('someID').innerHtml = newVariablePassedFromGoogleScript;

  // OR EXAMPLE 3 just provide an alert
  window.alert(newVariablePassedFromGoogleScript+" was updated!");  // The date of 03/09/2021 was updated!
}

function on Failure(){
  alert('The process failed.  Try again.');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

7. and an example of the gs could be...

```
function someGsScript(date){
  Logger.log("The date passed from the webpage is "+date);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('yourSheetName').getRange(1,1).setValue(date);
  return "The date of "+date;
}
```

**SOME REFERENCES**

[HtmlService <-- Hyperlink](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

[createTemplateFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))

[.evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html)

[Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html)

[How web pages communicate with google scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

[.withSuccessHandler() return function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2)

In the grey boxes on the last link, make sure you look at both the Code.gs and the Index.html for the examples.

[W3Schools DOM Element objects](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

[W3Schools practice environment for getElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid)

:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I've now somewhat successfully implemented this bit into my HTML file. Now the issue is, that whenever I click on the +1 or -1 button, instead of increasing the date, a new tab opens up with a .......script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?...... address. It lists all the values in the textboxes, but it doesn't seem to accomplish the update of the date textbox. Do I need to adapt any settings perhaps? Thanks again!

Comment: Add `<base target="_top">` to your `<head>` tag like this... `<head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>`

Comment: I did already have that in there. Could it be that this doesn't work because it's an embedded sidebar?

Comment: Would you be willing to share your html file or the gs code that generates the html output?

Comment: Sure, I've just added the code to the question above (before adding your bit of code, but I guess that's most likely where the issue is located at, since I assume that it works standalone for you?).

Comment: You're a legend James! :) Thank you so much for taking the time to help me on this.
It did indeed work as intended now. I understood though, that the original plan of sending info from the .html over to the .gs for manipulating the data and then sending it back to .html doesn't work (at least the sending back doesn't, the first part I did actually get to work by passing the entire form element over to the .gs)
Could you point me to any resource that could help me understand why the changes to the .gs (.evaluate() and TemplateFromFile) were necessary or what they did?
Thanks so much again!

Comment: OK.  So I added a THEORY section and a REFERENCES section to the bottom.  I hope this helps.  And, I hope I didn't make a mistake. :)

Comment: That's absolute gold, James. It'll probably take me a while to compile all this and to develop a deeper understanding, but from what I've read this is exactly what I was looking for :). THANKS!!!